# How to replace a part of a string in a pandas.Dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am trying to replace a part of all strings in pd.Dataframe, but it doe s not work.

My data example:

```
HLAA0101    
HLAA0201    
HLAA0202    
HLAA0203    
HLAA0205
```

What am I trying to obtain:

```
A0101    
A0201    
A0202    
A0203    
A0205
```

My code:

```
 mhc = train_csv.mhc

 for i in mhc:
   i[0:2].replace('HLA', ' ')

 print(mhc)
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
df['mhc'] = df['mhc'].str[3:]
```

**Option 2:**

```
df['mhc'] = df['mhc'].str.replace(r'^HLA','')
```

**Option 3:**

```
df['mhc'] = df['mhc'].str.extract(r'HLA(.*)', expand=False)
```

**Option 4:** (NOTE: sometimes list comprehension works faster than internal vectorized methods for string/object dtypes)

```
df['mhc'] = [s[3:] for s in df['mhc']]
```

All options yield the same result:

```
In [26]: df
Out[26]:
     mhc
0  A0101
1  A0201
2  A0202
3  A0203
4  A0205
```

**Timing for 50.000 rows DF:**

```
In [29]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [30]: %timeit df['mhc'].str[3:]
35.9 ms ± 3.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [31]: %timeit df['mhc'].str.replace(r'^HLA','')
162 ms ± 3.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [32]: %timeit df['mhc'].str.extract(r'HLA(.*)', expand=False)
164 ms ± 4.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [33]: %timeit [s[3:] for s in df['mhc']]
14.6 ms ± 18.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [34]: df.shape
Out[34]: (50000, 1)
```

**Conclusion:** list comprehension approach won.

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
mhc = mhc.str.replace('HLA', ' ')
```

OR -

```
train_csv['mhc'] = train_csv['mhc'].str.replace('HLA', '') # One liner directly from df
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.replace`.
(Documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Also, in your code it inserts a space instead of the replaced strings. If you want that, that's fine, otherwise delete the space. ;)